# Number of Non-equivalent Generating Triples of Involutions in Finite Simple Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, involutions

Let $G$ be a group. We say $(x,y,z)\in G\times G\times G$ is a *generating triple of involutions* if $|x|=|y|=|z|=2$ and $\langle x,y,z\rangle = G$. A generating triple $(x,y,z)$ of $G$ is said to be *non-degenerate* if $\{x,y,z\}$ is a minimal generating set.

Let's say two generating triples $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are *equivalent*  if there exists $g\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ such that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)^g = (x_2,y_2,z_2)^\sigma$, where $\sigma\in S_3$ is a permutation of three entries.

It's known that every non-abelian finite simple group has a generating triple of involutions.

**My questions:**

1. How to find the number of non-equivalent generating triples of involutions of non-abelian finite simple groups? (In partucular, $A_n$.) (Added: or some bounds of this number?)
2. If $xy = yx$, then what's the number will be?

For the first question, I tried $A_5$ and $A_6$. $A_5$ is easy but $A_6$ needs a lot of time to calculate by hand. For the second question, only the following non-abelian finite simple groups cannot have (see the first 5 references of [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10469-019-09525-3)):
\begin{equation*}
A_6,A_7,A_8,L_3(q),U_3(q),L_4(2^n),U_4(2^n),S_4(3),M_{11},M_{22},M_{23},McL.
\end{equation*}

Comment: There is probably no "closed-formula" for this. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Well you could use a computer rather than trying to do it by hand!

Comment: Maybe finding a closed-formula is difficult, but is there any bound (it should be a function of $n$, if any) for $A_n$?@verret

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Derek Holt's suggestion, here is how one could do it in GAP:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("x","y","z");;
gap> g:=f/ParseRelators(f,"x2,y2,z2");;
gap> h:=AlternatingGroup(5);; # or whatever group you like
gap> GQuotients(g,h);
[ [ x, y, z ] -> [ (2,4)(3,5), (2,3)(4,5), (1,2)(3,4) ], ... 19 in total
```

This returns homomorphisms up to equality of kernels, which is I think exactly what you want. This is clearly limited by group order, but will be much quicker than doing it by hand.

If you also require that the first two generators commute, replace the definition of `g` by

```
g:=f/ParseRelators(f,"x2,y2,z2,[x,y]");
```